# GWT result.getSessionId() explanation

Tags: gwt, sessionid

I have no experience with session handling, and probably I'm just having a trouble getting the idea, but there is absolutely nowhere where the sessionId problem is explained.

First, I read [this Google article](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) and there is this statement:

```
String sessionID = /*(**Get sessionID from server's response to your
        login request.**)*/;"
```

So I started reading more, and I found [this tutorial](http://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/session-management-in-gwt/) - very helpful one, but it contains this line:

```
String sessionID = result.getSessionId();
```

and I do not simply know what to do with it! I have no such method defined in my User object (which is a result from a server response here). I can create it, but I don't know what to write in it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears in this tutorial the UserDTO is just storing sessionID in a map from BaseModelData from GXT.

You can see his code for this object at: https://code.google.com/p/yfs-health/source/browse/trunk/yfs/src/com/varun/yfs/dto/UserDTO.java

Basically at some point a UserDTO object is populated with this data from the HttpThreadLocalRequest during login on line 8 of LoginServiceImpl in the tutorial.

You can actually see it in action [here](https://code.google.com/p/yfs-health/source/browse/trunk/yfs/src/com/varun/yfs/server/login/LoginServiceImpl.java), the session id is set by analyzing the request in the servlet implementation:
`user.setSessionId(this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getId());`